# Не могу добавить элемент к циклу в Javascript

Tags: javascript, циклы, циклические-зависимости

У меня на странице цикл из 3ех изображений, мне нужно чтобы при клике помимо изображения внизу страницы менялась нумерация.

Для первого изображения "Стр. 1", для второго "Стр. 5-6", для третьего "Стр. 7-8". И, соответственно, тоже обратить этот процесс в бесконечный цикл.

[image: изображение для бо'льшей наглядности]

```js
var i = 0;
var imgs = new Array('001U.jpg', '002U.jpg', '003U.jpg');

function imgsrc() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.src = imgs[i = ++i % 3];
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="001U.jpg" onClick="imgsrc();">
<div class="text" id="footer"> Стр. 1 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;
var imgs = [{
    path: '001U.jpg',
    page: 'Стр. 1'
  },
  {
    path: '002U.jpg',
    page: 'Стр. 5-6'
  },
  {
    path: '003U.jpg',
    page: 'Стр. 7-8'
  }
];

function imgsrc() {
  const image = document.getElementById("image");
  const page = document.querySelector('#footer');
  image.src = imgs[i = ++i % 3].path;
  page.innerHTML = imgs[i].page;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="001U.jpg" onClick="imgsrc();">
<div class="text" id="footer"> Стр. 1 </div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!